# Looking for a REGEXP for a number upto two decimal places

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying with this

```
        /-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)?(?:\.\d+)?$/
```

But this take more than two decimal places and also it is accepting the value ".00"

It should accept the following values
100.00
00.00
0
100
10000000000.00
98173827827.82

It should reject the following values
.00
10.098
87.89381938193819
9183983109.9283912
10.aa
adjbdjbdj

I'm new with the regular expressions

**PS:- I'm trying the following code for javascript.
Therefore Please Restrict the expression to javascript only.**

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

This one should do :

```
/^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/
```

Comment: for testing and a nice visualization what this regex does - [debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/IQS8Abrz8_Ozf-f9)

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like:

```
/-?(?:\d{1,3}(?:,?\d{3})+)?(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (/^\d+([,.]\d{1,2})?$/im.test(value)) {
        alert("ACCEPTED\n" + value);
    } else {
        alert("REJECTED\n" + value);
    }
}
```

<kbd>[JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NRXf9/5/)</kbd>

**REGEX EXPLANATION**

```
^\d+([,.]\d{1,2})?$

Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character) (line feed, line feed, line separator, paragraph separator) «^»
Match a single character that is a “digit” (ASCII 0–9 only) «\d+»
   Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «([,.]\d{1,2})?»
   Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
   Match a single character from the list “,.” «[,.]»
   Match a single character that is a “digit” (ASCII 0–9 only) «\d{1,2}»
      Between one and 2 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «{1,2}»
Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character) (line feed, line feed, line separator, paragraph separator) «$»
```